# Is there a way route complex API methods by convention-based routing using MVC4 and WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can we route

```
GET TestService/{guidId}/Items?var1="A1"&var2="A2"
```

(where `guidId` parameter will pass `Guid` value), using convention-based routing with MVC4 and WebAPI1?

I know this can be achieved through Attribute Routing using MVC5 and WebAPI easily.

Is there anyway using ASp.Net MVC4 to achieve above request?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a controller and action like this

```
public class TestServiceController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetItems(Guid guidId, string var1, string var2) { ... }
}
```

A convention-based route can be mapped like this

```
// Convention-based routing.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ItemsApi",
    routeTemplate: "TestService/{guidId}/Items",
    defaults: new { controller = "TestService", action = "GetItems" }
);
```

Given `GET TestService/{guidId}/Items?var1="A1"&var2="A2"`

the model binder will match the `{guidId}` from the route and extract `var1` and `var2` from the query string